# iOS static-dynamic libraries size comparison

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I recently converted one of my static libraries into a framework, because I use it in extensions and I wanted to reduce my app's size (which worked like a charm). I'm thinking about converting other static libraries into frameworks. But they are only used in one target. I know frameworks have other benefits, but I wonder:

- Objective C linker can strip dead code of a static library, but it can't of a framework (I think). So technically, static libraries can take less space than dynamic libraries (assuming they have the same source code and target it is embedded into does not use all of its symbols). Is that assumption true?
- Does -ObjC flag on an app target prevents dead code stripping of static libraries linked to it? If so, does it mean that the dynamic and static library sizes would be equal?